# experimental analysis of running times in extendable table

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, arrays

I was given the following homework question:

> Implement an extendable table using arrays that can increase in size
>   as elements are added. Perform an experimental analysis of each of the
>   running times for performing a sequence of n add methods, assuming the
>   array size is increased from N to the following possible values:
>
> - 2N
> - N + ceiling(√N)
> - N + ceiling(log N)
> - N + 100

I'm just a little confused about what this question is asking, and was hoping for some help/clarification. The way I understand it, you could implement something like this in Python with a two-dimensional array (the "extendable table"), and then append varying numbers of values for each scenario. Am I understanding the implementation correctly?

Then, I'm also a bit unclear on what number of values you'd be appending. Would you literally first test it with say, 16 values, then 32 (2N), then 20 (ceiling(√N)), etc? Or is it more complex than that?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you want to understand what your instructor wants you to do, you should ask your instructor, not us here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extendable array *isn't* a two-dimensional array (I don't know what's an extendible *table*). The idea is that you start with an array of a fixed size, and each time you are trying to insert an element into the array but it's full, you increase the size from $N$ (its current size) to $f(N)$ (its subsequent size, until it needs to be enlarged again). That means that you allocate new memory ($f(N)$ items), copy the old array into the new place, and then free the old memory. When you have added $f(N)-N-1$ more elements, a subsequent insertion would require enlarging the array to size $f(f(N))$, and so on. The question is what is the best choice for the function $f$.

Experimentally, you can try different functions $f$. For each such suggestion $f$ (and the *same* initial size of the array, say something like 20 or 100, you decide), plot $n$ against the time it takes to add $n$ elements (what elements you add isn't important; you could just add zeroes), averaged over several trials. I'll let you decide how exactly to do that, but you probably want several different values of $n$, and $n$ as large as roughly a million or so (you decide exactly how large). You can then find which function is better than others. I suggest you use C rather than python in your experiments.